# How to remove all instances of a specific character from a string?

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to remove all of a specific character from a string. I have been using `String.Replace`, but it does nothing, and I don't know why. This is my current code:

```
        if (Gamertag2.Contains("^"))
        {
            Gamertag2.Replace("^" + 1, "");
        }
```

This just leaves the string as it was before. Can anyone please explain to me as to why?

Comment: Did you try Regular Expression?

Comment: @Sandeep Regular Expressions would overcomplicate a straightforward issue.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You must assign the return value of [`String.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx) to your original string instance:

hence instead of(no need for the `Contains check)`

```
if (Gamertag2.Contains("^"))
{
    Gamertag2.Replace("^" + 1, "");
}
```

just this(what's that mystic `+1`?):

```
Gamertag2 = Gamertag2.Replace("^", "");
```

Comment: @Ian - I'm not convinced.  Unless there's something you're not telling us, `Gamertag2 = Gamertag2.Replace("^", "");` will definitely remove any instance of "^".  Set a break point after the `String.Replace` and see if it removes "^" from `Gamertag2`.

Comment: a string is immutable - which means you need to assign it to something.  .Replace will return a new string.

Comment: Does this replaces all occurances or just the first match?

Comment: @yılmaz all occurrences

Comment: I've been writing C# for years, and I still make this mistake occasionally! I wish Visual Studio could be configured to warn on these types of useless method calls without assignments (https://stackoverflow.com/q/26280971/12484).

Comment: @JonSchneider: I get ["Return value of pure method is not used"](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/ReturnValueOfPureMethodIsNotUsed.html) in this case. It reminded me again why i should decorate my methods with the `Pure` attirbute if possible, thanks :)

Answer (score 15):

Two things:

1) C# Strings are immutable.  You'll need to do this :

```
Gamertag2 = Gamertag2.Replace("^" + 1, "");
```

2) `"^" + 1`?  Why are you doing this?  You are basically saying `Gamertag2.Replace("^1", "");` which I'm sure is not what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Like climbage said, your problem is definitely

```
Gamertag2.Replace("^"+1,"");
```

That line will only remove instances of "^1" from your string. If you want to remove all instances of "^", what you want is:

```
Gamertag2.Replace("^","");
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is old and also that my solution may be inefficient to the extreme, but it replaces all occurrences of a string. Found that if I was looking for "\r\n\r\n\r\n" to replace with "\r\n\r\n" a single Replace() didn't catch all.

Therefor this:

```
do // First get rid of spaces like "  \r"
{
  str = str.Replace(" \r","\r")
} while (str.Cointains(" \r"));

do // Then remove the CrLf's in surplus.
{
  str = str.Replace("\r\n\r\n\r\n","\r\n\r\n")
} while (str.Cointains("\r\n\r\n\r\n"));
```